# Access the word that comes after a specific element in a paragraph

Tags: javascript

I have the following HTML:

```
<p>
    So many frogs were falling out of the sky 
    <sup>
        <span id="footnote-1">1</span>
    </sup> 
    that the even the priests
    <sup>
        <span id="footnote-2">2</span>
    </sup> 
    didn't know what to do.
</p>
```

*Assuming I cannot change the structure of the HTML itself*, how can I use Javascript to modify the word that comes *directly after* any arbitrary footnote when the user clicks on said footnote?

Example: the user clicks `footnote-2` and then the word "didn't" turns red.

Some vague ideas, none of them wonderful.

1) Fancy regex?

2) Wrap every word in the paragraph with a `<span>` tag, then select on that?

Thanks for any help.

Shell code, just to be explicit.

```
document.getElementById('footnote-2').addEventListener('click', function(){
    // something something something...
    // the word "didn't" is now red.
});
```

EDIT: Answers in jQuery are fine, as per a question below.

EDIT 2: I was not nearly explicit enough in my original description of the problem.

EDIT 3: Semantics.

Comment: Can I use jQuery in my answer?

Comment: Anyone wants to help, I'm willing to look.

Comment: Step 1 will have to be to fix the HTML, having a `div` inside a `sup` is invalid. `sup` can only contain *phrasing content*. `div` is *flow content*. (It does matter, the browser may reorder things to try to fix it.)

Comment: Do you want `don't` to toggle between red and normal?

Comment: I don't actually care what happens to `don't`. I just want to modify it. This is part of a much larger idea.

Answer (score 1):

*"1) Fancy regex?"* Definitely not. :-)

Step 1 will have to be to fix the HTML, having a `div` inside a `sup` is invalid. `sup` can only contain *phrasing content*. `div` is *flow content*. (It does matter, the browser may reorder things to try to fix it.) For the purposes of this answer, I'm going to replace those `div` elements with `span`s.

(**Note:** The question originally wasn't clear about the OP not being able to change the HTML, and in fact seemed to say he/she could. Keep reading, we move on to creating the `span` programmatically later.)

Instead, wrap the first word in a span as you said:

```
<p>
    So many frogs were falling out of the sky 
    <sup>
        <span id="footnote-1">1</span>
    </sup> 
    <span class="firstword">that</span> the even the priests
    <sup>
        <span id="footnote-2">2</span>
    </sup> 
    <span class="firstword">didn't</span> know what to do.
</p>
```

...then add a class to that span when the footnote is clicked. You can get the span in the handler like this:

```
this.parentNode.nextElementSibling
```

Find the footnotes by any common characteristic; you might add a class to them, but you can select them as is via `[id^=footnote-]` (matches any element whose `id` starts with `"footnote-"`).

So for instance:

```
function footnoteClick() {
    this.parentNode.nextElementSibling.classList.add("active");
}
document.querySelectorAll('[id^=footnote-]').forEach(function(e) {
    e.addEventListener('click', footnoteClick);
});
```

Or more defensively, that `footnoteClick` might be:

```
function footnoteClick() {
    var sib = this.parentNode.nextElementSibling;
    if (sib && sib.classList.contains("firstword")) {
        sib.classList.toggle("active");
    }
}
```

...and you might use `toggle` rather than `add` so the red goes on and off on repeated clicks.

Live Example (with `toggle`):

```js
if (typeof NodeList !== "undefined" &&
    NodeList.prototype &&
    !NodeList.prototype.forEach) {
    Object.defineProperty(NodeList.prototype, "forEach", {
        value: Array.prototype.forEach
    });
}

function footnoteClick() {
    var sib = this.parentNode.nextElementSibling;
    if (sib && sib.classList.contains("firstword")) {
        sib.classList.toggle("active");
    }
}
document.querySelectorAll('[id^=footnote-]').forEach(function(e) {
    e.addEventListener('click', footnoteClick);
});
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<p>
    So many frogs were falling out of the sky 
    <sup>
        <span id="footnote-1">1</span>
    </sup> 
    <span class="firstword">that</span> the even the priests
    <sup>
        <span id="footnote-2">2</span>
    </sup> 
    <span class="firstword">didn't</span> know what to do.
</p>
```

---

In a comment you've said you can't change the HTML structure. You're going to **have** to change the HTML structure, though, to fix the `div`-inside-a-`sup` problem. But if you can't also put the first word following the footnotes in spans, we can handle that part dynamically; see comments:

```
function footnoteClick() {
    var sib = this.parentNode.nextElementSibling;
    if (!sib || !sib.classList.contains("firstword")) {
        // This is the first time, we have to wrap the
        // word in a span; create the span
        sib = document.createElement("span");
        sib.classList.add("firstword");
        // Get the text node
        var textNode = this.parentNode.nextSibling;
        // Remove leading and trailing whitespace
        textNode.nodeValue = textNode.nodeValue.trim();
        // Find the end of the first word
        var endIndex = textNode.nodeValue.indexOf(" ");
        if (endIndex != -1) {
            // Have to split it
            textNode.splitText(endIndex);
        }
        // Insert the span and move the word into it
        textNode.parentNode.insertBefore(sib, textNode);
        sib.appendChild(textNode);
    }
    if (sib) {
        sib.classList.toggle("active");
    }
}
```

Live Example (with `toggle`):

```js
if (typeof NodeList !== "undefined" &&
    NodeList.prototype &&
    !NodeList.prototype.forEach) {
    Object.defineProperty(NodeList.prototype, "forEach", {
        value: Array.prototype.forEach
    });
}

function footnoteClick() {
    var sib = this.parentNode.nextElementSibling;
    if (!sib || !sib.classList.contains("firstword")) {
        // This is the first time, we have to wrap the
        // word in a span; create the span
        sib = document.createElement("span");
        sib.classList.add("firstword");
        // Get the text node
        var textNode = this.parentNode.nextSibling;
        // Remove leading and trailing whitespace
        textNode.nodeValue = textNode.nodeValue.trim();
        // Find the end of the first word
        var endIndex = textNode.nodeValue.indexOf(" ");
        if (endIndex != -1) {
            // Have to split it
            textNode.splitText(endIndex);
        }
        // Insert the span and move the word into it
        textNode.parentNode.insertBefore(sib, textNode);
        sib.appendChild(textNode);
    }
    if (sib) {
        sib.classList.toggle("active");
    }
}
document.querySelectorAll('[id^=footnote-]').forEach(function(e) {
    e.addEventListener('click', footnoteClick);
});
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<p>
    So many frogs were falling out of the sky 
    <sup>
        <span id="footnote-1">1</span>
    </sup> 
    that the even the priests
    <sup>
        <span id="footnote-2">2</span>
    </sup> 
    didn't know what to do.
</p>
```

---

Side note: The `forEach` method on the NodeList returned by `querySelectorAll` is relatively new; for older browsers you may have to polyfill it:

```
if (typeof NodeList !== "undefined" &&
    NodeList.prototype &&
    !NodeList.prototype.forEach) {
    Object.defineProperty(NodeList.prototype, "forEach", {
        value: Array.prototype.forEach
    });
}
```

For **really** obsolete browsers like IE8, you may have to polyfill `Array.prototype.forEach` first.

---

The various operations above are covered in the DOM specs: https://www.w3.org/DOM/DOMTR

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, it made me realize I didn't give a good enough description of the problem. In this scenario, I cannot modify the structure of the HTML itself. Any changes must be done in javascript only. When I said "wrap every word in a span tag," I literally meant every word.

Comment: You can grab the text content, parse the first word out of the string and reinsert new HTML in any case. The original DOM can be worked around to suit your usecase.

Comment: As in, split the string on every instance of `</sup>`?

Comment: You want the next word visible on page right after whatever is inside `#footnote-2`, correct? Generically finding that `textNode` is one separate problem, but once you do have it, you can modify anything inside of it. As you say you'd split the string, modify it and reinsert it where the textNode was.

Comment: @crowhill: Well, I"m afraid you're going to have to change the HTML structure because it's invalid and it's invalid in a way that forces the browser to rearrange things. When you do that, will also also be able to put the first word in a span, or do we have to handle that part dynamically?

Comment: @crowhill: I've added an example handling the situation where you can't wrap the first word in a span until runtime.